# What does "make a crowd of someone" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "make a crowd of someone" mean? A man recalls how he as a five-year-old got lost once. Wells's short story The Door in the Wall

> And he must needs bring in a kindly young policeman and **make a crowd of** me, and so march me home.

Comment: Not to mention "he must needs bring in..."

Comment: @cruthers - He must needs = he had to do it, he insisted on doing it (with a note of exasperation).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it means that he caused a crowd to gather around the boy. I doubt this is standard usage any more, but I'd be interested to know if anyone else has heard it used in this particular way. I certainly haven't. It's possible that this is just Wells bending the language to his liking.

Comment: People used to talk like that when I was a kid. I was born and raised not far from Bromley, where Wells grew up.